# How to Reset line numbers in minted code?

Tags: tex-core, minted

i have a portion of code in minted package:

```
\begin{minted}[
 frame=single,
 numbersep = 1pt,
 breaklines=true,
 framesep=1mm,
 baselinestretch=1,
 bgcolor=LightGray,
 fontsize=\footnotesize,
 linenos
 ]{java} 
 package test.multiple_interactions;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {static{System.loadLibrary("threadLeak"); //"libthreadLeak.so"}
 public static native void send(String data);
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String imei = tel.getDeviceId();//source
 String[] arr = new String[10];
 arr[1] = imei;
 send(arr);}}
 \end{minted}
```

I want to reset line numbers in middle of my code and start it from 1 again. is that possible in minted package?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main changes based on your (incomplete) example:

- option `escapeinside=||` is added to `minted` environment
- code snippet `|\setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{1}|` is appended after java code line `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){`. Here `FancyVerbLine` is the counter used in line numbering.

Note: This may break other line-number `minted` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[
    frame=single,
    numbersep = 1pt,
    breaklines=true,
    framesep=1mm,
    baselinestretch=1,
    bgcolor=LightGray,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    linenos,
    escapeinside=||
  ]{java} 
  package test.multiple_interactions;
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
      {static{System.loadLibrary("threadLeak"); //"libthreadLeak.so"}
  public static native void send(String data);
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){|\setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{1}|
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei = tel.getDeviceId();//source
    String[] arr = new String[10];
    arr[1] = imei;
    send(arr);}}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]